# Select everything with where clause that fulfills all dates in the range?

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT fc,cohort, value
FROM test.input_test
WHERE value IS NULL AND date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-09-30';
```

I would like to select all rows where the value is null in the whole data range (not only on some specific dates).

Answer (score 0):

One method is window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fc, cohort, value
FROM (SELECT it.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN it.value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () as null_cnt
      FROM test.input_test it
      WHERE it.date >= '2019-07-01' AND it.date < '2019-10-01'
     ) it
WHERE null_cnt = 0;
```

Note that I changed the date comparisons to avoid `BETWEEN`.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a good blog explaining why `BETWEEN` is a bad idea with dates.  Most of the points are relevant even if you do not use SQL Server.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is **not** a bad idea with `DATE` values - it's only a bad idea with `timestamp` (or `datetime`)  values.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an exists clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fc, cohort, value
FROM test.input_test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-09-30' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test.input_test
                WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-09-30' AND
                      value IS NOT NULL);
```

As @Gordon mentioned, if you want to include the entire months of July, August, and September 2019, then the date range you should use is:

```
WHERE date >= '2019-07-01' AND date < '2019-10-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly try below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT IT.fc, IT.cohort, IT.value
FROM test.input_test AS IT
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT fc,cohort, value 
    FROM test.input_test 
    WHERE value IS NOT NULL AND date BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-09-30'
) AS QUERY_2 ON IT.fc = QUERY_2.fc AND IT.cohort = QUERY_2.cohort AND  IT.value = QUERY_2.value
WHERE QUERY_2.fc IS NULL
```